# Plot Indicator for Visible Data Only

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

I've been trading with Tradingview's built in linear regression channel indicator lately and I find it to be very handy as it saves me a lot of time I would otherwise spend plotting price channels and regression channels myself. One thing I find very annoying though is having to change the lookback period length to more accurately accomodate price. I thought it would be great if the indicator would automatically re-adjust to display a regression channel of only the bars that are visible on my screen, similar to how VPVR re-adjusts.

Since there is no source code for Tradingview's VPVR in pine editor that I can copy, could someone please kindly tell me how to alter the code for the regression channel to the effect of the above?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Linear Regression Channel", shorttitle="LinReg", overlay=true)

lengthInput = input.int(100, title="Length", minval = 1, maxval = 5000)
sourceInput = input.source(close, title="Source")

group1 = "Channel Settings"
useUpperDevInput = input.bool(true, title="Upper Deviation", inline = "Upper Deviation", group = group1)
upperMultInput = input.float(2.0, title="", inline = "Upper Deviation", group = group1)
useLowerDevInput = input.bool(true, title="Lower Deviation", inline = "Lower Deviation", group = group1)
lowerMultInput = input.float(2.0, title="", inline = "Lower Deviation", group = group1)

group2 = "Display Settings"
showPearsonInput = input.bool(true, "Show Pearson's R", group = group2)
extendLeftInput = input.bool(false, "Extend Lines Left", group = group2)
extendRightInput = input.bool(true, "Extend Lines Right", group = group2)
extendStyle = switch
    extendLeftInput and extendRightInput => extend.both
    extendLeftInput => extend.left
    extendRightInput => extend.right
    => extend.none

group3 = "Color Settings"
colorUpper = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 85), "", inline = group3, group = group3)
colorLower = input.color(color.new(color.red, 85), "", inline = group3, group = group3)

calcSlope(source, length) =>
    max_bars_back(source, 5000)
    if not barstate.islast or length <= 1
        [float(na), float(na), float(na)]
    else
        sumX = 0.0
        sumY = 0.0
        sumXSqr = 0.0
        sumXY = 0.0
        for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
            val = source[i]
            per = i + 1.0
            sumX += per
            sumY += val
            sumXSqr += per * per
            sumXY += val * per
        slope = (length * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (length * sumXSqr - sumX * sumX)
        average = sumY / length
        intercept = average - slope * sumX / length + slope
        [slope, average, intercept]
        
[s, a, i] = calcSlope(sourceInput, lengthInput)
startPrice = i + s * (lengthInput - 1)
endPrice = i
var line baseLine = na
if na(baseLine) and not na(startPrice)
    baseLine := line.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, startPrice, bar_index, endPrice, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorLower, 0))
else
    line.set_xy1(baseLine, bar_index - lengthInput + 1, startPrice)
    line.set_xy2(baseLine, bar_index, endPrice)
    na
    
calcDev(source, length, slope, average, intercept) =>
    upDev = 0.0
    dnDev = 0.0
    stdDevAcc = 0.0
    dsxx = 0.0
    dsyy = 0.0
    dsxy = 0.0
    periods = length - 1
    daY = intercept + slope * periods / 2
    val = intercept
    for j = 0 to periods by 1
        price = high[j] - val
        if price > upDev
            upDev := price
        price := val - low[j]
        if price > dnDev
            dnDev := price
        price := source[j]
        dxt = price - average
        dyt = val - daY
        price -= val
        stdDevAcc += price * price
        dsxx += dxt * dxt
        dsyy += dyt * dyt
        dsxy += dxt * dyt
        val += slope
    stdDev = math.sqrt(stdDevAcc / (periods == 0 ? 1 : periods))
    pearsonR = dsxx == 0 or dsyy == 0 ? 0 : dsxy / math.sqrt(dsxx * dsyy)
    [stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev]
    
[stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev] = calcDev(sourceInput, lengthInput, s, a, i)
upperStartPrice = startPrice + (useUpperDevInput ? upperMultInput * stdDev : upDev)
upperEndPrice = endPrice + (useUpperDevInput ? upperMultInput * stdDev : upDev)
var line upper = na
lowerStartPrice = startPrice + (useLowerDevInput ? -lowerMultInput * stdDev : -dnDev)
lowerEndPrice = endPrice + (useLowerDevInput ? -lowerMultInput * stdDev : -dnDev)
var line lower = na
if na(upper) and not na(upperStartPrice)
    upper := line.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, upperStartPrice, bar_index, upperEndPrice, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorUpper, 0))
else
    line.set_xy1(upper, bar_index - lengthInput + 1, upperStartPrice)
    line.set_xy2(upper, bar_index, upperEndPrice)
    na
if na(lower) and not na(lowerStartPrice)
    lower := line.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, lowerStartPrice, bar_index, lowerEndPrice, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorUpper, 0))
else
    line.set_xy1(lower, bar_index - lengthInput + 1, lowerStartPrice)
    line.set_xy2(lower, bar_index, lowerEndPrice)
    na
linefill.new(upper, baseLine, color = colorUpper)
linefill.new(baseLine, lower, color = colorLower)
    
// Pearson's R
var label r = na
label.delete(r[1])
if showPearsonInput and not na(pearsonR)
    r := label.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, lowerStartPrice, str.tostring(pearsonR, "#.################"), color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.new(colorUpper, 0), size=size.normal, style=label.style_label_up)
```

Comment: I think you want the `confirm` parameter. Check if this is [helpful](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-scripts-are-now-interactive-27147/)

Comment: This lets me draw the indicator right? Not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like to modify the indicator to include only the visible range. This is more like a fixed range.